# Bridson’s algorithm for Poisson-disc sampling on Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

I try to program the `Bridson’s algorithm for Poisson-disc sampling` on scratch, it seams to be some side effect or a bug I can't find. Could you help me ?

**Here is my try :** [My try online.](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/114080375/)

[Some explanation on the algorithm.](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/)

[image]

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did put a link on my code, if it's not enough tell me how to past Scrtach code in my post ?

Comment: link may die in future so it would be good if you can share the code snip where exactly you need help, just add the code to the post, I will help you in formatting and guide, as I don't know **mit-scratch** technology, but as a reviewer I can help you in making better question, which will bring quick answers from people around the SO community.

Comment: I added the code like it looks like in Scratch.

Comment: Just give us the .sb2 file, and if you really do have to use an image, **in English** please

Comment: Sorry for the language. If you click on the link "My try" you will see an icon "See inside", click on it and you will see the codein the language you want and even will able to run and modify it. I will put the .sb2 online in a minute and update the english version of the image. Than you for your help.

Comment: @YotamSalmon the .sb2 file is an archive with .xml, .png ... files in it, I can't past it to the SO editor, and on can't read it but in scratch. It is why I put the link on MIT site where one can find, use and edit it in the language one wants.

Answer (score -2):

Found the bug.
The answer is on the same link as in the question.
Thank you.

Nothing important, an obvious mismatch in indexes.

Comment: Nothing important, an obvious mismatch in indexes. Thank you for your involving.